# Index Error - Python - EMNIST dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, mnist

I've been trying to construct a neural network to train the EMNIST datasets. The two segments of code below are in entirely different cells in jupyter notebook however they are the two that cause the error stated below. My problem comes from the fact that for one dataset the code runs fine then for this particular dataset i receive an error. If anyone could tell me where i've been going wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
IndexError: index 540774 is out of bounds for size 540774 

def dense_to_one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes):
   num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
   index_offset = np.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
   labels_one_hot = np.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
   labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
   return labels_one_hot

test_labels_flat = test_data_labels[["1"]].values.ravel()
test_labels_count = np.unique(test_labels_flat).shape[0]
test_labels = dense_to_one_hot(test_labels_flat, test_labels_count)
test_labels = test_labels.astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive - you are accessing an element beyond what is in some list/tensor/array. If you want anybody to help you, you would need to give much more information than this. What is the exact stack trace? What are the corresponding lines of your code? What is the size of the array you are accessing? Why do you expect it to be larger? etc.